# Is there any script to convert folder images into one pdf

Tags: python, windows, pdf

I have many folders and inside that i have many images. Now i want one PDF per folder so that all images contained in folder goes into PDF. I have 1000s of folders so i want something which can batchprocess or which can walk in the folder and start processing things.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool that does this? Or an idea how to do this in python?

Comment: If there is a ready to use tool , that will be good , otherwise i am looking for python script which can make one pdf from images in folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd solve this with ImageMagick, and not with Python. ImageMagick has the console tool 'convert'. Use it like this:

```
convert *.jpg foo.pdf
```

See [here](http://bitprison.net/jpg_to_pdf). (Depends on whether you use Windows, Mac or Linux, should be easy to find out with Google)

Comment: The original post says "I have 1000s of folders so i want something which can batchprocess or which can walk in the folder and start processing things." This answer doesn't really address that situation at all, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to do the same thing.  It uses the Python (2.7 not Python 3)and the reportlab package downloadable from here http://www.reportlab.com/software/installation/ and loops thru all the subdirectories of what you set "root" to and creates one pdf of all the jpegs in each folder.

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader


root = "C:\\Users\\Harry\\" 

try:
   n = 0
   for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
       PdfOutputFileName = os.path.basename(dirpath) + ".pdf" 
      c = canvas.Canvas(PdfOutputFileName)
      if n > 0 :
           for filename in filenames:
                LowerCaseFileName = filename.lower()
                if LowerCaseFileName.endswith(".jpg"):
                     print(filename)
                     filepath    = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                     print(filepath)
                     im          = ImageReader(filepath)
                     imagesize   = im.getSize()
                     c.setPageSize(imagesize)
                     c.drawImage(filepath,0,0)
                     c.showPage()
                     c.save()
      n = n + 1
      print "PDF of Image directory created" + PdfOutputFileName

except:
     print "Failed creating PDF"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running for loops through your documents using something like this:

```
def __init__(self, location):
  if os.path.isdir(location): # search directory
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.png')):
    print 'current file is: %s' % infile
```

Within the for loop I would suggest using a library such as [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)